# Sometime Webdriver not able to find webelement and throw nosuchelementexception but many times same test runs perfectly

Tags: java, html, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I created a test script in which i want to click a edit button and then close the window. Most of the time the code works as expected but some time for the same code i gets nosuchelement exception. I went through the similar questions asked in the forum but none of the solution worked for me. Below i am putting the java code along with the HTML Code in hope to find a solution.

```
for(String newwindow : window.getWindowHandles()){
    //swithching to the new pop up using window.switchTo().window(passing newwindow as argument)    
    window.switchTo().window(newwindow);}
    //getting title of new window using getTitle() method
    System.out.println("NewWindow Title"+ window.getTitle());
    window.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='edit_resume_section3_open' and not(@disabled)]")).click();
    window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.println(window.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='title']")).getAttribute("value"));
    window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    window.findElement(By.id("update")).click();
    window.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(40, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    window.close();

Html Code for the webelement-
<head>
<body class="bg_lightgreen" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" onload="" leftmargin="0"    topmargin="0" style="">
<iframe id="_yuiResizeMonitor" style="position: absolute; visibility: visible; width: 10em; height: 10em; top: -120px; left: -120px; border-width: 0px;"/>
<div id="fade_nation_mismatch" class="black_overlay"/>
<div id="fade_visual_resume" class="black_overlay"/>
<div id="show_visual_resume" class="white_content" style="position: absolute; top: 25%;">
<table class="bg_purple" width="100%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0">
<table class="bg_white" width="998" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" border="0" align="center">
<table class="bg_white" width="998" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="20" border="0" align="center">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="font_15 txt_purple bold" width="203" style="padding-bottom:5px; width:250px; word-wrap: break-word;">1.6YR Experiance/BSC(CS)</td>
<td width="715" style="padding-bottom:5px;">
<a id="edit_resume_section3_open" class="thickbox" title="Professional Details"  style="cursor:pointer" onclick="showEditSection(3);">[Edit]</a>
</td>
</tr>
```

Below code is for the button which is giving problem
    [Edit]

Answer (score 1):

Try to use

```
WebElement yourElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 10))
  .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("yourElementId")));
```

to be sure that your element will be loaded, then you can work with your element. Or another ExpectedConditions

Answer (score 0):

It may take longer to load sometimes, so you can wait until the element is loaded up to a maximum time instead of using implicitlyWait:

```
private void waitUntilIsLoaded(WebDriver driver, By selector, int maxTime){
   wait.wait(driver, selector, maxTime);
}
```

You can also modify your code to take a screenshot when the test fails to check that the element is displayed, because it may not be loaded due to some error.